# CSS grid item positioning inside div

Tags: css

I'm working with this part of code:

```
<div class="row">
  <h2>Row title</h2>
  <span class="test">table cell</span>
  <span>table cell</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <h2>Row title</h2>
  <span>table cell</span>
  <span>table cell</span>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <h2>Row title</h2>
  <span>table cell</span>
  <span>table cell</span>
</div>
```

My question is if I do:

```
.row {
    grid-column: span 3;
}
```

Is it possible to place items inside this spanned cells like this without flexbox on `<div>`?
[image: click this image please]

Comment: if you want every row and columns to match, then you need to remove the .row class element and keep all h2/spa sibblings  : css example removing .row with display:contents (not crossbrowser)  https://jsfiddle.net/fzb23eju/

Comment: This is what subgrid is designed for.

Comment: or display:table https://jsfiddle.net/fzb23eju/1/  untill subgrid is widely supported ;)  https://caniuse.com/#search=subgrid  ;) @Paulie_D  *Old, not obsolete* ...

Comment: I don't understand is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4ofkhnwr/) what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not with just that,

```
.row {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    padding: 10px;
 }
```

this will give you the required behaviour. You may have to add extra styling to this.

Check -> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-column.asp for reference.

---

also the `grid-column` property is mostly used to style an individual item. That too in combination with `display: grid` property on the wrapping element

Comment: the problem is that columns from a .row to another .row won't match ... display:table-row/table-cell is probably what the ops wants . see my comment about display:contents for the grid idea ...  ;)

Comment: makes sense, This would work only in case the content length is strictly similar. But i quiet could'nt get table like behavior from the question

Comment: from the screenshot, 2 white rows and a red one   ...  the table idea https://jsfiddle.net/fzb23eju/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can, use the `align-items:` and `justify-items:` properties to move the content inside the flex box around

If you need a guide i would suggest looking at this https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/tutorials/center-and-align-items-in-css-grid/

Comment: op dosent want a flex box based solution

Comment: You can use those properties with the grid also

Comment: could you detail your explanation? would love to know

Comment: He wants to know how to align text in the grid sections, please click the link and scroll down about half way and you will see if you use align-items on a grid layout, they will align vertically in the grid, if you set justify-items it will align the elements horizontal in the grid sections

Comment: (repeating ) the problem is that columns from a .row to another .row won't match ... display:table-row/table-cell is probably what the ops wants . see my comment about display:contents for the grid idea ... ;)  and the fiddle associated

Comment: Fair enough, my best attempt was only able to achieve using flex which i know he said he did not want https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-dust-7hkpz but his main aim was to get the text in his grid in the centre right?